# Docker installed from snap fails to receive remote network traffic

Tags: ssl, docker, self-signed-certificate

I have an API hosted on a docker image which worked in the past, but which now is failing to work except on the host machine. I can successfully run queries using either localhost or the machine's local IP address from the host machine, but when I try to query from a remote computer, I get the "EOF occurred in violation of protocol" error, both from my browser and from the `requests` Python package. This error started occurring after I was forced to purge and reinstall docker (using snap on Ubuntu 20.04) due to a mysterious error that made the docker daemon impossible to run. I am using self-signed certificates generated as follows:

```
openssl req -x509 -new -addext "subjectAltName = \"IP.1:<machine's local IP address>, DNS:localhost\""  -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -nodes
```

UPDATE: This appears to be a problem with Docker. I tested the `strm/helloworld-http` container and it also works locally but not remotely.

Does anyone have any idea what might cause this error?

Comment: I fixed this problem by purging docker according to the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker and then reinstalling docker using the apt repository instructions here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/.